# How to sum all numbers in the form of scientific notation in bash

Tags: awk

I have a data file like this

```
  1.59949146E+01  1.59949146E+01  1.59949146E+01  1.59949146E+01  1.59949146E+01
  1.59949146E+01  1.59949146E+01  1.59949146E+01  1.59949146E+01  1.59949146E+01
  1.59949146E+01  1.59949146E+01  2.39850450E+01  2.39850450E+01  2.39850450E+01
  2.39850450E+01  2.39850450E+01  2.39850450E+01  2.39850450E+01  2.39850450E+01
  2.39850450E+01  2.39850450E+01  2.39850450E+01  2.39850450E+01
```

To sum all the numbers, I use the following code

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ print $i}}' number.txt |awk '{printf ("%f ", $0)}' |awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ print $i}}'|paste -sd+  | bc
```

First, it changes all raws to a single column

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ print $i}}' number.txt 

1.59949146E+01
1.59949146E+01
1.59949146E+01
1.59949146E+01
1.59949146E+01
1.59949146E+01
1.59949146E+01
1.59949146E+01
1.59949146E+01
1.59949146E+01
1.59949146E+01
1.59949146E+01
2.39850450E+01
2.39850450E+01
2.39850450E+01
2.39850450E+01
2.39850450E+01
2.39850450E+01
2.39850450E+01
2.39850450E+01
2.39850450E+01
2.39850450E+01
2.39850450E+01
2.39850450E+01
```

Using `awk '{printf ("%f ", $0)}'` I will have the following output

```
15.994915 15.994915 15.994915 15.994915 15.994915 15.994915 15.994915 15.994915 15.994915 15.994915 15.994915 15.994915 23.985045 23.985045 23.985045 23.985045 23.985045 23.985045 23.985045 23.985045 23.985045 23.985045 23.985045 23.985045
```

Again I need to use `awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ print $i}}'` to convert raws to a column and then using `paste -sd+  | bc` I can have the answer

```
479.759520
```

Although it works I'm looking for a better way to reduce the steps.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I have the correct output (i.e. 479.759520). I need to learn how to use sophisticated commands in bash to have better code.

Comment: `xargs -n 1 <file | awk '{sum+=$0} END{print sum}'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this single `awk` for this:

```sh
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) sum += $i} END {print sum}' number.txt

479.76
```

or using `printf`:

```sh
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) sum += $i} END {printf "%f\n", sum}' number.txt

479.759515
```

If you have `gnu awk` then use:

```sh
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '{sum += $1} END {print sum}' number.txt
```